# Leer correo electrónico gmail con java

Tags: java, email, gmail, read

Mi problema consiste en no poder leer un correo electrónico programado en java a través del servidor de gmail, ya habilite el pop3 desde la configuración de correo y sigo sin lograr el objetivo.

Este es el error que me arroja "**Couldn't connect to host, port: pop.gmail.com, 995; timeout -1;**" y mi código es el siguiente:

```
package Consultas;

import javax.mail.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Session;

public class JavaMail_reademail {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchProviderException, MessagingException{
        
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        // Deshabilitamos TLS
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "false");
        // Hay que usar SSL
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" );
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        // Puerto 995 para conectarse.
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.port","995");
        prop.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", "995");
       
        Session sesion = Session.getInstance(prop);
        //sesion.setDebug(true);
        Store store = sesion.getStore("pop3");
        store.connect("pop.gmail.com","correo@gmail.com","pwss");
        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        
    }
    
}
```

Espero y puedan ayudarme se los agradeceré mucho.

Comment: Haz lo siguiente, ve a https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords y genera una contraseña para la app de correo electrónico con el nombre del dispositivo que quieras y usa esa contraseña para conectarte a google desde tu app de java. Las políticas de seguridad de google no permiten consumir la app directamente con tu contraseña. Hazme saber si te funcionó. Yo lo acabo de probar con tu código sin ningún problema.

Comment: Ahora el problema es que no me deja acceder a ese sitio "myaccount.google.com/apppasswords " me dice que "La opción de configuración que buscas no está disponible para tu cuenta."

Comment: ¿Es una cuenta empresarial o es personal? Aquí puedes ver más detalles si no te quedaron claro los pasos https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=es-419. Aunque imagino por qué no la puedes usar. Seguro no tienes activada la verificación en dos pasos.

Comment: Es una cuenta personal. ya estoy investigando como acceder a esa seccion "Contraseñas para aplicaciones"

Comment: Oye un favor me puedes decir que opciones seleccionaste para generar la contraseña?, ya hice un intento y no me funciono quizás y me estoy equivocando en la selección de opciones.? https://postimg.cc/kDzYFBkP

Comment: Seleccionar app > Correo Electrónico. Seleccionar Dispositivo > Otro > Java App. Click en Generar y luego copias la contraseña. En tu código de java la línea `store.connect("pop.gmail.com","correo@gmail.com","pwss");` pones tu correo real y la password que generaste.

Comment: No me funciono :( después de generar la contraseña para aplicaciones, cambiaste tu contraseña de ingreso normal por la generada?

Comment: Literal https://ibb.co/QJJ3bC4 es tu código corriendo. Le agregué unas líneas para imprimir los mensajes. ¿Puedes agregar la traza del error completa? Sí, la contraseña que se pone en el código es la generada.

Comment: Una disculpa por la tardanza, no podía editar la pregunta para añadir mi salida como código. Tomé captura de pantalla de la salida en GlassFish 5.0.1, usando JDK 1.8 y netBeans 12.4. Agradezco de antemano su tiempo y esfuerzo prestados

https://postimg.cc/gallery/0mN30th

Comment: La verdad ni idea que es lo que pasa. Parece ser algo en tu entorno. Yo te recomiendo hagas una "_prueba de concepto_" a ver si es tu cuenta o es algo en tu servidor. Crea un proyecto separado para tu código y ejecútalo con solo las dependencias necesarias. Un proyecto limpio, cómo este: https://file.io/ydaZr9vFrIWv . He intentado verificar si puedo reproducir tu error, desactivando hasta pop en mi cuenta, poniendo errores en el usuario y contraseñas pero en todas las ocasiones (y utilizando tu mismo programa) obtengo errores super significativos, nada que ver con lo que muestras.

Comment: Asegúrate de tener en tu pom [javax.mail-api 1.6.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api/1.6.2) y su [implementación de sun 1.6.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.6.2).

Comment: Después de varios días comprobé que si funciono tu solución, agradezco mucho de tu asesoría.